# How do I know if an app is already installed on iPhone from Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, google-analytics

I'd like to know if is it possible to **check from Safari via Javascript if there is a specific app already installed**. 
I'm doing a login form for an application from the web that goes into the app and I'd like to call that application. I'm using that code right now:

```
{% if request.ios %}
            var backup_url = window.location + "&no_app=True";
              setTimeout( function()
              {
                  document.location = backup_url;
              }, 200);
            window.location = "{{ apple_url }}";
{% endif %}
});
```

There is a check to know if the device is an iOS device. After that I check if the '&no_app=True' is appended on the url. If it is appended I don't need to check it. 
Otherwise I have a 200ms where I wait to append it and I try to open the app with: 'window.location = "{{ apple_url }}";'

I'd like to track people with Google Analytics so I need to know if the app is installed, in this way I'm just hoping that it is. 
Do anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take a look at [Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to do this is to have the other app support a unique custom URL scheme. You can then ask the system if there are any apps installed that will respond to your custom scheme. If the answer is yes, you can be sure the other app is installed and ready to run.